# Passing Data from one view to another in tab bar controller not passing on time

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

this might be an easy question but after trial and error I am not able to obtain the results I am looking for. I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs, in which it passes an object (NSString) between the views. The string that I pass through does not show up on the label until after a second click. What I mean is in view A I have string "name", when I go to view B, I have a label which obtains its text from the string sent by view A, unfortunately, this does not show up. When I go to view C the label does show, and when I go back to view B the label has been populated. The same happens if I go to view C first before view B. Here is my code:

View A controller:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:    (UIViewController *)viewController
{
self.secondViewController = (StudentViewController *) [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
self.secondViewController.stName = studentName;

self.thirdViewController = (TeacherViewController *) [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
self.thirdViewController.stName = studentName;

}
```

View B Controller (Same set up for other views):

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stName;
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
studentName.text = stName;
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I have tried adding this on the view did load method but no luck. Any thoughts? Thank you for your help!

Comment: How and where is studentName declared?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My question has been answered but if you have an alternative I created the string under implementation in the .m file, they come from a tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but it is not clear to me from the documentation that didSelectViewController is even supposed to be called before the view appears.  Why don't you try shouldSelectViewController instead?